# Add to List from codebehind C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a UL list in a ASPX page:

```
<ul id="tabs">
 <li id="tab1"><a href="ztab1.htm">Tab 1</a></li>
 <li id="tab2"><a href="ztab2.htm">Tab 2</a></li>
 <li id="tab3"><a href="ztab3.htm">Tab 3</a></li>
 <li id="tab4"><a href="ztab4.htm">Tab 4</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I would like to add list items dynamically from codebehind, including the href entry for each new list item.

How?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to mark your ul as a server side control, then treat the 'new item' as a `HtmlGenericControl` and insert it into the control collection:

```
<ul runat="server" id="tabs">
```

To add the item, create a new element and add it:

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
tabs.Controls.Add(li);

HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "page.htm");
anchor.InnerText = "TabX";

li.Controls.Add(anchor);
```

Comment: it should be tabs.Controls.Add(li)

Comment: Dim newLi = New HtmlGenericControl("li")
                Dim anchor = New HtmlGenericControl("a")
                anchor.Attributes.Add("href", itemrow.Item("reg_url").ToString().Trim())
                anchor.InnerText = itemrow.Item("conf_name")
                newLi.Controls.Add(anchor)
                eventList.Controls.Add(newLi)

Comment: Doesn't work - downvote ! Next time check your answer before posting code !@

Answer (score 10):

Use   [asp:bulletedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.aspx) and your list will be much easier.

```
<asp:BulletedList id="blTabs" 
  BulletStyle="Disc"
  DisplayMode="LinkButton" 
  runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="ztab1.htm">tab1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ztab2.htm">tab2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ztab3.htm">tab3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

Code Behind:

```
    ListItem li = new ListItem();
    li.Value = "*.html";  //html goes here i.e.  xtab1.html
    li.Text = "New Text";  //text name goes i.e. here tab1
    blTabs.Items.Add(li);
```

Answer (score 6):

This result is the same as GenericTypeTea's, but the difference is the HTML is 'written' in the code behind and injected into the page.

In your markup:

```
<asp:Literal id="litMarkup" runat="server" />
```

In your code behind:

```
List<string> locations  // however this initialized 

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<ul id=\"tabs\">");

for (int i = 0; i < locations.Count; i++)
{
   sb.Append("<li id=\"tab" + i.ToString() + "\"><a href=\"" + locations[i] + "\">Tab " + i.ToString() + "</a></li>");
}

sb.Append("</ul>");

litMarkup.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Awesome how I'm marked down on a perfectly workable and valid answer without any explanation.

Comment: It happens mate, don't take it personally. Some users are too cowardly to give an explanation for their downvote. I didn't give the downvote but I'm guessing you got it because this is an ill-advised way of doing it. Not because it doesn't give the same output, but because it's an absolute maintenance nightmare, a lot more code and quite unreadable. We banned this sort of code from our projects a long time ago. The `TagHelper` in ASP.Net MVC is a nice way of doing something similar to your answer though.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - Thanks for your explanation, I wasn't aware using a literal was considered a bad practice

Comment: I think this is a great solution and I think it will work for me. I will be testing it out and give update.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a dynamic UL by using an `asp:Repeater` Control

You can use repeater in following way, in your `.aspx` file

```
<asp:Repeater ID="menu_ul_1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <ul class="my-menu">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
        <a href='<%# Eval("href_li")%>'>
        <%# Eval("DisplayText")%></a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And you can put dynamic data via code behind in `.aspx.cs` file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable newsDataTable = new DataTable();

    // add some columns to our datatable
    newsDataTable.Columns.Add("href_li");
    newsDataTable.Columns.Add("DisplayText");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        DataRow newsDataRow = newsDataTable.NewRow();
        newsDataRow["href_li"] = "?sc=item_" + i;
        newsDataRow["DisplayText"] = "List Item # "+i;
        newsDataTable.Rows.Add(newsDataRow);
    }
    menu_ul_1.DataSource = newsDataTable;
    menu_ul_1.DataBind();
}
```

**Result:** You will get following html through this code

```
<ul class="my-menu">
    <li><a href='?sc=item_1'>List Item # 1</a> </li>
    <li><a href='?sc=item_2'>List Item # 2</a> </li>
    <li><a href='?sc=item_3'>List Item # 3</a> </li>
    <li><a href='?sc=item_4'>List Item # 4</a> </li>
    <li><a href='?sc=item_5'>List Item # 5</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow... Awesome! How can I convert your code to use SQL connection? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565614/how-to-use-dataset-instead-of-datatable-in-c-sharp

Comment: I actually got it work but how can I manipulate the class for the different `LI`?

Answer (score 0):

nested it with parent child,use your elements as below

```
Dim newLi = New HtmlGenericControl("li")
        Dim anchor = New HtmlGenericControl("a")
        anchor.Attributes.Add("href", itemrow.Item("reg_url").ToString().Trim())
        anchor.InnerText = itemrow.Item("conf_name")
        newLi.Controls.Add(anchor)
        eventList.Controls.Add(newLi)
```