# How to manipulate li element from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have application which generate some pages from some templates. My template is `.aspx` file which contain one `li` and some content with it. There are more then one template on generated page so I **can't** do it using:

```
<li runat="server" id="myLi">
...
this.form1.FindControl("myLi")
```

I really need to ad some data to this `li` by code behind becouse I use data from database.
How can I do this? Maybe some other solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an answer? Can you tell this more literal? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx) or [DetailsView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx)? They are meant to display one item (at the time) combine with [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx).

If you want to use explicit li DOM element as server control, you need to use [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx)

You need to have some selector - class or attribute to get only li that you need in this case.

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

HtmlGenericControl liItem = (HtmlGenericControl) ctl.FindControl("liItemID");
liItem.Attributes.Add("class", "someCssClass");
```

combined with and type check

```
foreach(Control ctrl in Page.Controls)
```

Comment: Have you read my whole question? I can't use `id` on my `li` element.

Comment: How do you pinpoit it in DOM - what will be selector here ?

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly manipulate the li element in ASP because it isn't a control.

But, this might help give you some ideas: [Add to List from codebehind C# Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530965/add-to-list-from-codebehind-c-sharp-asp-net)