# How to use DataSet instead of DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, htmlgenericcontrol

I have the following template which fills my `UL` with data received from a DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = getData(); //Insert your datasource here

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Attributes.Add("data-trait-id", row["TraitID"].ToString());

        HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
        a.Attributes.Add("data-trait-id", row["TraitID"].ToString());

        HtmlGenericControl span1 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span1.Attributes.Add("class", "name");
        span1.InnerText = row["Name"].ToString();
        a.Controls.Add(span1);

        HtmlGenericControl span2 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span2.Attributes.Add("class", "count");
        span2.InnerText = row["Count"].ToString();
        a.Controls.Add(span2);

        li.Controls.Add(a);
        ulSpecialty_selector.Controls.Add(li);
    }
```

But in my page I am using DataSet to get the columns from a SQL query:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDataShape;Data Provider=SQLOLEDB;" + "Data Source=svr;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=zh;Password=zha")) {
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SHAPE {SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[BookingTable]} ", connection);

            DataSet dsLocation = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dsLocation, "Location");
        }
    }
```

How can I use the first block of code to work with the second block of code so I can generate the `LI` inside the `UL`?

I am looking to emulate the following:

```
<ul class="ulLocation" id="ulLocation2_selector" runat="server">
    <li class="liSubLocation active" data-trait-id="9">
        <a href="/locations/new-york/neighborhoods?tags[]=12&amp;tags[]=66" class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="9">
        <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
        <span class="name">New Rochelle</span>
        <span class="count">6</span>
            </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you know that DataSets are just a collection of DataTables, and that you can essentially reference the DataTable the same way you're using it in the first block of code by loading it into a DataSet and referencing the first indexed table inside the DataSet. Like so.. DataSet dsLocation = new DataSet();  dsLocation.Tables[0] <- this is your datatable, essentially

Comment: DataTable dt = dsLocation.Tables[0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily convert DataTable to DataSet or vice-versa
DataTable from DataSet

```
//Assuming oDS is my DataSet
DataTable oDt =  oDS.Tables[0];// If you know name of datatable you may use oDS.Tables["name"]
```

DataSet from DataTable

```
//Assuming oDT is your DataTable
DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
oDs.Tables.Add(oDT);
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work but How can I emulate the LI from my question? Because it seems with BulledtedList I can't have child

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are returning a dataset from GetData(), you can change the following:

```
DataSet ds = getData();
DataTable dt;
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
}

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){
```

...

Comment: @Sikni8 You may be able to use a ASPX Repeater control.  Never used it myself, by it may work for you.