# Unable to show the data in databases

Tags: asp.net, api

I am using `Entity Framework` to access data in databases.
when I debug my code, the `List<Book> books` contains elements.
However, I can not show it in the HTML page.
If I declare new `List<Book>`, I can retrieve this
This is not working:

```
 public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        List<Book> books = db.Books.ToList();
        return books;
    }
```

However, this is working:

```
public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        List<Book> books = new List<Book>
        {
            new Book {BookId =1, Title="hehe",AuthorId=1,Genre="Trinh Tham" },
            new Book {BookId =2, Title="Kaka",AuthorId=2, Genre="Sport"}
        };
        return books;
    }<br />
```

This is my html page:

```
<ul id="books"></ul>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('api/Books/GetBooks').done(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                $("#books").append("<li>" + item.Title + " - " + item.Genre + "</li>");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you build the list within the c#/asp.net framework?   It wouldn't be too hard ....Please see [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530965/add-to-list-from-codebehind-c-sharp-asp-net)

Build the ul elements within the html, then add the li from code-behind

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this before.  It is most likely a JSON serialization error that won't show up when you are debugging the api controller. To view the actual error message, just copy and paste the url in your browser and it will show the error message. SO if you are debugging in visual studio, just go to http://localhost:[portnumber]/api/Books/GetBooks

If I had to guess, I would say that you have associations (foreign keys) such as Author that are causing the issue. What usually happens is your Entity Framework connection gets disposed before your list can be serialized which throws an error.  So you have a few options:

You can create a custom class such as BookJson and just have what you want to be serialized in it so that way your return object has all of the data in it before your api controller goes to serialize it. Plus you can only get the information that you need to serialize instead of the entire object. It would look something like this:

```
public class BookJson
{
  public int BookId {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public string AuthorName {get; set;}
  public string Genre {get; set;}
}

public IEnumerable<BookJson> GetBooks()
{
    return db.Books.Select(x => new BookJson { BookId = x.BookId, Title = x.Title, AuthorName = x.Author.Name, Genre = x.Genre}).ToList();
}
```

Another option is to use the .Include in your db call which will make Entity Framework go ahead and fetch that related data before it gets disposed & serialized. You just need to make sure you include all of your related entities. So something like this:

```
db.Books.Include("Author").ToList();
```

The last option is similar to the previous one except you are just disabling lazy loading on the entity framework context so that all related entity data is retrieved. To do this you would just set this option on your data context with:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.Books.ToList();
```

Comment: I have seen again the article about that in asp.net. I following exactly the same thing. However, the data is still not shown. It also includes the first option of your answer.

Comment: What are you getting when you load the url in the browser? Also you have to make sure your variables are public or they wont get serialized.